# When using socket.recv(), the program hangs up when there are no more bytes to read

Tags: python, sockets, recv

I am receiving several binary messages in a stream.  Each one is parsed according to an ID and length within the message.  I want to read all sent messages; however, if I try and receive more bytes than have been sent, the program hangs up until the previously set socket.settimeout().

How I would like to handle this:

```
while end_of_file == 0:
    header = socket.recv(6)
    if header == '':
        end_of_file = 1
```

Does not work because it is always expecting 6 more bytes.

Comment: That's not correct. It isn't 'always expecting 6 more bytes'. It will return as soon as even one byte has been received, or the peer closes the connection. Until either happens, it will block.

Comment: Which language is this?  Looks a bit like Python but who knows with no tags.

Answer (score 3):

You said it yourself:

> if I try and receive more bytes than have been sent, the program hangs up

What you have described is *normal* behavior if the socket is running in *blocking* mode (which is the default).  You tell it to read, and it waits until new data arrives.

If you don't want it to wait forever, you have to either:

1. call [`socket.settimeout()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/socket.html#socket.socket.settimeout) and then handle the [`timeout`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/socket.html#socket.timeout) exception if it occurs during reading.
2. use [`select.select()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/select.html#select.select) to detect when the socket has pending data to read before you then call `socket.recv()` to read it.

Comment: how does select.select() work? + does it work on Windows

Comment: @AK_ Read the documentation. `select()` is a standard socket function on all platforms that support BSD style sockets, including Windows, *Nix, etc.

Answer (score 2):

The client will not know that the server did not send more data unless the server will tell it. This means that

- either the server has to tell the client up-front how many data to expect
- or the server will send some special data to indicate that no more data are coming
- or the server should should close the connection, which also indicates that no more data are coming (i.e. recv will return). Note that this only works when there is a connection, that is with TCP but not with UDP.

Comment: In this case, the server is sending the message length followed by the message data.  So the client knows how many bytes to expect per message. It sounds like the message header (including the message length) is 6 bytes.

Comment: I don't know how you conclude this behavior from the posted code, but if this is the case the server would need to finish the data stream with a message containing 0 as the encoded length. The client could use this to know that the server is done sending. This would be similar to chunked transfer in HTTP.

Comment: the poster said: "I am receiving several **binary messages** in a stream. Each one is parsed according to **an ID and length within the message**".  That means each message has a header that describes the message. So the client has to read the header (usually a fixed sized) and then read the message based on what the header says.

Comment: You are right. Although it is not clear from this description if the server will send a last record to indicate end of data.

Comment: It doesn't matter if it does or not.  Most protocols do not, nor is it necessary.  Since the client is reading message-by-message, either a message arrives or the socket is closed. The client should be prepared for both. In the interim, yes the socket is going to block the caller while the socket is idle, unless non-blocking semantics are used. That is simply how socket programming works, in every language and every platform.

Comment: I think it is not necessary to argue when we have not enough information. It is not even clear that the communication is with TCP, but with UDP there is no connection close. And obviously there is no connection close here after the last message, otherwise recv would return with error. This might be because in reality their are multiple message streams, each with its own end (like multiple requests in HTTP with keep-alive) or because they communicate with UDP. Again, too much information are lacking in the question.